# how check integer value with db string having integer boundaries in the format of 1 to 10 in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like below format, and Condition is age between values in nvarchar format

```
Id  Condition
1   0 to 10
2   10 to 20
3   20 to 30
4   30 to 40
5   40 to 50
6   50 Above
```

now I would like to retrieve id value at runtime age need to be check with the table condition column according to the matching boundary.

could you please help on this query?.

Comment: Do you have any validation on the text of the condition field? Could I just insert "As old as Gandalf"? Could you possibly refactor this to a MaxConditionAge and MinConditionAge columns?

Comment: Change your structure with a minAge and maxAge column, instead of these ugly varchars ?

Comment: Age 10 comes in which range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with SWeko.
If you cannot change the types, it seems you are fortunate to have a simple linear progression, so this will work too.
NB: THIS IS A NON-OPTIMUM SOLUTION

```
DECLARE @InputAge TINYINT = 31

;WITH MyTable (Id, Condition) AS
(
-- Corrected age overlaps
    SELECT 1, '0 to 10'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '11 to 20'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '21 to 30'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '31 to 40'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '41 to 50'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, '51 Above'
)
SELECT Id
FROM MyTable 
WHERE @InputAge BETWEEN 10 * Id-9 
                AND CASE WHEN Id = 6 THEN 150 ELSE 10*Id END
```

The string manipulation operation would be something like this. This is also a very poor performer!

```
DECLARE @InputAge TINYINT = 35

;WITH MyTable (Id, Condition) AS
(
-- Corrected age overlaps
    SELECT 1, '0 to 10'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '11 to 20'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '21 to 30'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '31 to 40'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '41 to 50'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, '51 Above'
)
SELECT   Id
        ,LEFT(Condition, CHARINDEX(' ', Condition))
        ,RIGHT(Condition, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Condition)))
FROM MyTable 
WHERE @InputAge BETWEEN LEFT(Condition, CHARINDEX(' ', Condition)) AND ISNULL(NULLIF(RIGHT(Condition, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Condition))), 'Above'), 255)
```

Comment: +1 for actually taking the time to write that out! shame it will probably end up in production over a non destructive database change ;)

Comment: yeah... poor models are sadly what keep me employed most of the time ;)

Comment: A quote from a friend of a friend - "I love UDF's, deleting and inlining them are the easiest money I make"

Answer (score 2):

If you have any power over the structure of the tables, change this to a `(ID, MaxAge, MinAge)` format, and then your query is something like:

```
select p.*, r.ID as AgeBracket 
from people p
  inner join ageRestrictions r 
    on p.Age between r.MinAge and r.MaxAge
```

If the structure of the table is set in stone, than mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to restructure that table and use SWekos code, but to answer your question directly:

if it is exactly as you have described there is a relationship between age and range id that you can exploit in a **HELLUVA DIRTY HACK**:

```
select 
    CASE p.age
      WHEN  p.age < 70 THEN p.age %10 + 1
      ELSE 6
FROM People as p
```

;)

Comment: please don't actually do this unless its a one off activity